# Proof of the infamous Happy Number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Suppose you take a natural number of any number of digits. You square each digit of that number and add all the outputs. You get another number by doing this. Repeat this process with the new number. Continue this process until you end up with a single digit number. There's a catch. If the number is not $1$ or $4$ write the single digit number as $01$, $02, $03$ and so on, and continue the process.

Prove that the single digit number obtained at the last will either be $1$ or a $4$.

---

I have no idea how to prove this. I tried with a two digit number. I assumed the number as $10a+b$ and the new number will be $a^2+b^2$. But after this I was stuck. Like what if I took $11$ and then the new number will be $02$ and then we will get $4$.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sketch:  Usually one does this sort of thing by showing that there is some $N\in \mathbb N$ such that, assuming the claim is true up to $N$, then it holds forever.  That comes down to remarking that, for a sufficiently large $n$, your process produces a lower value.

Comment: Let $f$ be the function mapping an input number to it's output after applying this process.  My first instinct would be to try to prove a statement along the lines of $n>100\implies f(n)<n$.  If we manage to do that, then we could argue that whatever number we started with, however large, will eventually after repeated application of $f$ get us into a smaller finite range of values which can be checked manually if need be, and if we tighten the bound could make it a very small number of cases to check.

Comment: "*There's a catch... write the single digit number as 01, 02, 03 and so on and continue the process*"  I don't see why this should have mattered.  Squaring an existent zero and adding that accomplishes the same thing as having not included a zero in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For large numbers the sum of digit squares is smaller, for example at most 81 million for one million digit numbers, 49+7*81=616 for numbers up to 81 million, 5^2+2*81 for numbers up to 616, 162 for numbers up to 187.

Then you make a table of the values for numbers up to 162 and check.